# intellij 2 programming languages in one folder

Tags: python, perl, intellij-idea, scripting

I use IntelliJ IDEA as a perl and python editor currently I have it set up as follows:

```
scripts/python <- python sources
scripts/perl   <- perl sources
```

I would love to simply have all my scripts in a scripts folder, i.e:

```
scripts <- contains both .py and .pl files
```

but if I do that I have to designate the script folder as either a "python" or a "perl" module and thus loose tab completion for one of the two languages

How can I mix my sources into the same folder without loosing tab completion, I never build or run any of my scripts from the IDE as I am a data scientist and thus need to deploy my scripts on a more beefy server. So if a solution breaks any of these javaish features I don't mind.

metadata about IntelliJ version

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
Build #IC-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b343 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

TLDR; Is it possible to have tab completion for two different languages if they source files are in the same folder